# Retrieve data values from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to retrieve the `OrderID`, `SessionID` and `URL` values from an XML response. I am a newbie please.
I have tried the following code but not working.

```
$orderID = $response->TKKPG->Response->Operation->Order->OrderID;
$sessionID = $response->TKKPG->Response->Operation->SessionID;
$URL = $response->TKKPG->Response->Operation->Order->SessionID;

echo $orderID;
echo $sessionID;
echo $URL;
```

But this seams not to be working.

See the XML below

```
$response = "<TKKPG><Response>
    <Operation>CreateOrder</Operation> 
    <Status>00</Status>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>83916</OrderID>
      <SessionID>6C94CDCB27E9EF48DA9B94119887E681</SessionID>
      <URL>returnpage.php</URL>
    </Order>
  </Response></TKKPG>"
```

Comment: `$response` is a string. Have you fed it to an XMLReader?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

simplexml_load_file — Interprets an XML file into an object. so you can easily get the data into the object.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data you show is a string. You have to feed that string to an XMLReader, like simpleXML like this. Then the items within the XML string are converted to a PHP object and the object is  addressed like this.

```
$response= "<TKKPG><Response><Operation>CreateOrder</Operation><Status>00</Status><Order><OrderID>83916</OrderID><SessionID>6C94CDCB27E9EF48DA9B94119887E681</SessionID><URL>returnpage.php</URL></Order></Response></TKKPG>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

print_r($xml);

echo $xml->Response->Order->OrderID . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->Response->Order->SessionID . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->Response->Order->URL . PHP_EOL;
```

Results

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Operation] => CreateOrder
            [Status] => 00
            [Order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [OrderID] => 83916
                    [SessionID] => 6C94CDCB27E9EF48DA9B94119887E681
                    [URL] => returnpage.php
                )

        )

)
83916
6C94CDCB27E9EF48DA9B94119887E681
returnpage.php
```

> Reference [SimpleXML in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Thank alot. It is working perfectly and i got the desired result.